# Having trouble with an append using multiple joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables: GROUPS, PROVIDERS and CORE. Below are the relevant fields within each table.

GROUPS: GroupID, Name, ID, ID2

PROVIDERS: SSN, GroupName, GroupID, GroupID2

CORE: RecordID, ID

I am attempting to insert the GroupID from GROUPS and RecordID from CORE into a table of their own, acting as a sort of bridge table.

The joins are occurring between GROUPS.GroupID = PROVIDERS.GroupID, CORE.RecordID = PROVIDERS.SSN and PROVIDERS.GroupName, GroupID, GroupID2 = GROUPS.Name, ID, ID2

GROUPS.GroupID and ID2 may, in some cases, but NULL or blank.

I am running a query directly from the PROVIDERS table and getting a hair under 14k records. The queries that I've attended produce nearly 1.5k more than that.

If there's something I could provide that would help, please let me know. I'm just looking for help with how I approach the problem, not necessarily the SQL.

```
INSERT INTO Group_Provider_Bridge (RecordID, GroupID)
SELECT DISTINCT
CORE.RecordID, GROUPS.GroupID
FROM CORE INNER JOIN PROVIDERS ON CORE.SSN = PROVIDERS.SSN INNER JOIN GROUP
ON PROVIDERS.GroupName = GROUPS.Name AND GROUPS.ID IS NULL OR GROUPS.GroupID = ""
GROUP BY CORE.RecordID, GROUPS.GroupID
```

The above is the SQL that I initially tried to append a PORTION of the data. The rest of the data was accomplished by joining on GroupID where GroupID IS NOT NULL. The resulting two queries appended ~1.5k more records than the query showed it should have.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Sample data and expected results would help also.

Comment: What is the trouble? Do you not want 1.5k records? Why would you want to insert GroupID and RecordID into a table of their own? If you want a dataset of all possible combinations of GroupID and RecordID, why is Providers table involved? All possible combinations of GroupID and RecordID would be a query without a JOIN clause - this is a Cartesian relationship where every record of each table is associated with every record of other table.

Comment: @June7 There are certain Records associated with other certain Groups. I'm getting approx. 1.5k more from the append than I should. The Providers table is involved because it has both the SSN and the group information, while the other two tables only have one. Not the other.

Comment: Think you should do as WEI_DBA suggests for us to be of any further help.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I've edited the original post to include the query(s) that I've used.